# How to register/login user in wagtail by uing api.V2

Tags: wagtail

I want to register new user/ login user in wagtail website by api.V2. Because I want to use react as frontend. How to do it.?

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail's API is documented as:

> The Wagtail API module exposes a public, read only, JSON-formatted API which can be used by external clients (such as a mobile app) or the site’s frontend.

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html

This means that the API is not mutable, and public, it does not provide any authentication or write (POST) functionality.

If you wish to request this feature may I recommend you [raise an issue on the Wagtail repository](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues).

There may be third party packages that provide this functionality though, alternatively you could explore building what you need with the included [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

If you want to read more on how to build a SPA (single page app) with Wagtail, here are some resources:

- https://leanpub.com/react-wagtail
- https://github.com/AccordBox/wagtail-react-blog
- https://github.com/Frojd/Wagtail-Pipit
- https://wagtail.org/blog/getting-started-with-wagtail-and-graphql/